# How can I centre merged columns with tabulary?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, multicolumn, tabulary

I'm trying to centre the content of the cells but I can't do it in merged cells. It's working properly in normal cells, but isn't working in merged cells.

Does anyone knows how to fix it?

Here is my code

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabulary,booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tabulary}{\linewidth}{C|C|C|C|C|C|C|}

\toprule

\multicolumn{7}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{13cm}}{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet} \\

\midrule
\midrule

\multicolumn{7}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{13cm}}{Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes} \\

\midrule

\multicolumn{7}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{13cm}}{Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus.} \\

\midrule

Vivamus Integer tincidunt  & elementum & semper & nisi & Aenean & vulputate & eleifend \\

\midrule

Donec & vitae & sapien & libero Integer tincidunt & venenatis & faucibus & libero \\

\bottomrule

\end{tabulary}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Comment: What is exactly your problem? Using your code (with the `tabulary` and `booktabs` packages) and replacing the `C` option for the `multicolumn` by a `c` it works and everything is centred. So I guess your problem comes from the `C` which should be a `c`, or I haven't understood your problem...

Comment: The problem using the `c`, is if the title is bigger than the page width, it doesn't wrap.

Comment: Which other package do you use because if I use only `tabulary` and `booktabs` the `C` option is not recognized and it gives errors?

Comment: For the tables I just use `tabulary` and `multirow`. It's not giving errors. It's working in normal cells, but in merged cells, the tabulary centers the text in the space for just one cell.

Comment: In which class?

Comment: give a look in my edit to see what happens

Comment: Could you add a full MWE to your question starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}` recreating your problem?

Comment: @LudovicC. `C` should be recognised, it is the built-in column type of `tabulary`.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Yes it is, I was unclear it is not recognized in the `multicolumn` command.

Comment: @LudovicC. It's recognised there, it just does the wrong thing. Blame the package author for a rubbish interface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure I have fully understood your problem but here is a way to make a table with the first row wrapping in a `multicolumn`. Obviously you will have to adapt the length in the `m{}` column descriptor to your need.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabulary,booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabulary}{\linewidth}{CCCC}
\toprule
\multicolumn{4}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{2.65cm}}{Table This is a very long title for my table} \\
\midrule
\midrule
0 & 14 & 18 & 32 \\
\midrule
1 & 47 & 67 & 114 \\
\midrule
5 & 81 & 61 & 142 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabulary}

\end{document}
```

This yields this output:

[image: Output1]

**Note**

If you want to automate a little bit the process you can use the `tabularx` environment instead and define a general length for your table in your preamble.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularx,booktabs}

\newlength{\tablelength}
\newlength{\titlelength}
\setlength{\tablelength}{6cm}
\setlength{\titlelength}{\tablelength}
\addtolength{\titlelength}{-1.5em}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabularx}{\tablelength}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X>{\centering\arraybackslash}X>{\centering\arraybackslash}X>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\toprule
\multicolumn{4}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{\titlelength}}{Table This is a very long title for my table} \\
\midrule
\midrule
0 & 14 & 18 & 32 \\
\midrule
1 & 47 & 67 & 114 \\
\midrule
5 & 81 & 61 & 142 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

It yields this output

[image: Output 2]

Comment: almost there! but for some reason, the cells get different sizes now.. i'm going to edit the question with the real table to you see.

Comment: @Wagner I saw your edit in the question but what do you want to do? Do you want all the cells (of the last rows) to have the same width? If yes then you should use a `p` or `m` descriptor and set them to a given length.

Comment: I'm using a XSLT to convert tables from XHTML to LaTeX. So, I can't just set a fix value to the cell width. Because there are many tables with many different styles. What I want to know is if there is any way to set equal widths to the cells no matter how many cells exists. Do you know whether it's possible?

Comment: The only solution I know is to use `tabularx` with the `X` columns descriptor. However you might be aware that it can sometimes be messy (e.g. your table, some words do not break as they should or as you would like them to).

Answer (score 4):

For a general span it's not so easy with the current `tabulary` interface but here you are spanning the full table so you know the exact width in advance is `\linewidth` minus the width of the rules and cell padding:

Note that using vertical rules and `booktabs` is an odd combination as that package intentionally aims for a design without vertical rules.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabulary,booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tabulary}{\linewidth}{|C|C|C|C|C|C|C|}

\toprule

\multicolumn{7}
{|>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{\dimexpr\textwidth-2\tabcolsep-2\arrayrulewidth}|}
{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet} \\

\midrule
\midrule

\multicolumn{7}
{|>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{\dimexpr\textwidth-2\tabcolsep-2\arrayrulewidth}|}
{Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes} \\

\midrule

\multicolumn{7}
{|>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{\dimexpr\textwidth-2\tabcolsep-2\arrayrulewidth}|}
{Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus.} \\

\midrule

Vivamus Integer tincidunt  & elementum & semper & nisi & Aenean & vulputate & elei\-fend \\

\midrule

Donec & vitae & sapien & libero Integer tincidunt & venenatis & faucibus & libero \\

\bottomrule

\end{tabulary}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I've been going nuts trying to figure out what I'd screwed up so my table's horizontal and vertical lines didn't connect anymore. I'd seen the `\toprule` etc in this question and thought: "Oh, I should use that. Why shouldn't I make use of other's automated spacing work?" Now I know. Removing vertical lines is a HORRIBLE choice. They could easily have designed it so that it works great if you leave them out, but then also works fine if you leave them in, when they're needed. Instead of extending functionality, they've replaced functionality.

Comment: @TravisBemrose how could they (actually one person) have easily done that? Have you looked at the source? Not to mention that the booktabs package documentation makes it absolutely explicit that not using vertical rules was part of the design aim for producing the package not just something that got broken along the way.

Comment: I've not reviewed the source but I'm convinced nothing is easy in TeX. However, when one is producing a package for public use, extra effort to "get it right" is called for (more than one would put into a single doc). I realize that it was a design choice they made; my point is that it's an extremely poor design choice. They could encourage the disuse of vertical lines, one can get away with that in many small tables that look fine. However there are tables that *demand* the use of vertical lines, and now one must trade one feature set for another. The option to use both is taken away.

Comment: @TravisBemrose no point in complaining to me I'm just the messenger but the booktabs package doc is somewhat famous for not being at all equivocal the package author thinks that vertical lines are one of the worst things that anyone can inflict on a human being and that making a table package that doesn't support them is doing it right. You might disagree (actually I disagree sometimes)

Comment: @TravisBemrose  but it makes no sense to disagree and use his package. and honestly it would _not_ be easy to do otherwise, the spacing around horizontal rules in latex tables is over-tight mainly to make coding the interaction with vertical rules tractable, and booktabs adds vertical space around horizontal rules so that _will_ break vertical rules unless you somehow re-implemented the entire table mechanism.

Comment: I didn't mean to complain to you. I was trying to thank you for clarifying that it was known that booktabs causes the gaps I was getting.